# send value from textarea and hidden using ckeditor

Tags: jquery, html, forms, textarea, ckeditor

I have a textarea and i want take the value from this and pass at an hidden input

HTML

```
<form action="load_art.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<!-- same strings-->
<textarea id="area"  onchange="submition();" ></textarea>
<input type="hidden" name="text" id="text"/>
<input type="submit"  value="Salva" />
</form>
```

JQUERY

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
CKEDITOR.replace( 'area' );
});
function submition(){
    $('#text').val($('#area').val());
    }
</script>
```

When i write into textarea using ckeditor the value not appear in value of hidden input.
without ckeditor the script work.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `.getData()`

```
function submition(){
    var areaText = CKEDITOR.instances['area'].getData();
    $('#text').val(areaText);
    }
```

check this working [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/C7N7r/30/)

Comment: @RiccardoGenioburgercondoppiob It is working for me. check this JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/C7N7r/30/ But I have modified a little. Instead of `onchange` I used `onclick` for a button (for the purpose of testing)